# Read uncommited data in Spring JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, locking, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

My service method in Spring Boot Application is accessed by several threads and one thread is modifying the data in DB.

When the other thread access the data before first commit, it will not get the db updates of earlier thread.

I have used following annotation to the relevant method after long search on stackoverflow.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Isolation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public void accept(Event<String> event) {}
```

But desired result could not be achieved. Uncommitted changes are not retrieved in second thread.

Please help me on this issue.

I have used entity manager flush() method but it was not successful.

Comment: What isolation levels does your database support? And more importantly, why do you want another thread to read uncommitted data? Wouldn't it be better to just commit it?

Comment: If you need to access the data modified by the first thread, then your transactions depend on each other. `READ UNCOMMITTED` is not a solution for this. What kind of data are you writing/reading, and why do you need to access it before it's committed?

Comment: Actually On first thread I put a lock on particular data in DB. So that while it is accessed by one thread it should not be accessed by others. In my method first it get the data which are unlocked and put a lock for them and commit to DB. So that other threads should not pick up those entries. But unfortunately they are picking the same entries as they are not committed to DB yet.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL Db and it supports READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation. Please help me on this issue I have been messed up.

Comment: how do you "put a lock on particular data in DB"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up isolation levels and locks.

An isolation level of `READ_UNCOMMITTED` **allows** other transactions to see what your first transaction writes before it commits. It does not require this to happen and it also does not affect locks. But according to your comments what you really want to achieve is to properly lock database rows in a way, so that others can't access them.

The JPA way to do this would be query the data with the appropriate lock mode:

> Lock modes can be specified by means of the EntityManager lock method, the methods of the EntityManager, Query, and TypedQuery interfaces that allow lock modes to be specified, and the NamedQuery annotation.

(3.4.4 from the [JPA Specification](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiptZfz0-HYAhVEDJoKHVwxAEAQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotn-pub%2Fjcp%2Fpersistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec%2FJavaPersistence.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3YYYXoHlqYYe31KBFa0lRV))

You are probably interested in the "pessimistic" variants which prevent another transaction to read locked rows before they are committed (and therefore the lock released)

> If transaction T1 calls lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) or lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)onanobject,the entitymanager must ensure that neither of the following phenomena can occur:
>
> - P1 (Dirty read): Transaction T1 modifies a row. Another transaction T2 then reads that row and obtains the modified value, before T1 has committed or rolled back.
> - P2 (Non-repeatable read): Transaction T1 reads a row. Another transaction T2 then modifies or deletes that row, before T1 has committed or rolled back.

(3.4.4.2 from the [JPA Specification](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiptZfz0-HYAhVEDJoKHVwxAEAQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotn-pub%2Fjcp%2Fpersistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec%2FJavaPersistence.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3YYYXoHlqYYe31KBFa0lRV))

You can use these lock modes with Spring Data JPA by using the [`@Lock`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Lock.html) annotation.